# Binary tree interview: implement follow operation

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I was asked to implement a binary search tree with follow operation for each node `v` - the complexity should be `O(1)`. The follow operation should return a node `w` (`w > v`).
I proposed to do it in `O(log(n))` but they wanted `O(1)`
**Upd.** It should be next greater node

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: You can only get amortized O(1) for this operation. Worst case is still O(log(n)). Did you try showing that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am correct, but If you maintain pointers to parents for all left children, For every node v, if v->right exists then it shall be greater than v. Else, if it is a left child, then its parent shall be greater than the node.

Comment: I assume you still need insert/delete operations, i.e. tree is dynamic, right?

Comment: @ile Yes,insert and delete operations shall not be O(1), but follow operation shall be.

Comment: @Yakov does the tree have to be balanced? do you still need optimal time insertion/deletion?

Answer (score 5):

just keep the maximum element for the tree and always return it for nodes v < maximum.

Comment: You are right. The description says they only want any greater node, not the next greater node. Seems like this is more of an interview-2.0 question.

Comment: @Domi - Excuse me - it is a next greater node

Comment: @Domi - what is 2.0 question

Comment: @Yakov then this is not your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get O(1) if you store pointers to the "next node" (using your O(log(n) algorithm), given you are allowed to do that.

Comment: what if the node is a leaf?

Comment: I updated my answer. I was thinking of leaf nodes only, like a B+ - Tree.

Comment: I think you are right, if updates to the trees are no longer done in optimal time. For example, insertion and deletion are done in O(n)?

Comment: I believe it can be achieved with careful choosing of your "next nodes", otherwise with an unlucky deletion you would need to update all the nodes in the tree.

Comment: A single node deletion only requires extra work of updating the guy who pointed to you which is O(deletion + log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
int tree[N];

size_t follow(size_t v) {
    // First try the right child
    size_t w = v * 2 + 1;
    if(w >= N) {
        // Otherwise right sibling
        w = v + 1;
        if(w >= N) {
            // Finally right parent
            w = (v - 1) / 2 + 1;
        }
    }
    return w;
}
```

Where *tree* is a complete binary tree in array form and v/w are represented as zero-based indices.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to literally just have a `next` pointer on each node.

You can update these pointers in `O(height)` after an insert or remove (`O(height)` is `O(log n)` for a [self-balancing BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)), which is as long as an insert or remove takes, so it doesn't add to the time complexity.

Alternatively, you can also have a `previous` pointer in addition to the `next` pointer. If you do this, you can update these pointers in `O(1)`.

Obviously, in either case, if you have a node, you also have its `next` pointer, and you can simply get this value in `O(1)`.

**Pseudo-code**

For only a `next` pointer, after the insert, you'd do:

```
if inserted as a right child:
   newNode.next = parent.next
   parent.next = newNode
else // left child
   predecessor(newNode)
```

For both `next` and `previous` pointers:

```
if inserted as a right child:
   parent.next.previous = newNode
   newNode.next = parent.next
   parent.next = newNode
else // left child
   parent.previous.next = newNode
   newNode.previous = parent.previous
   parent.previous = newNode
```

(some `null` checks are also required).